# Fibonacci sequence in python giving out incorrect result instead of the right one

Tags: python

I am trying to implement the Fibonacci sequence in python

I am getting the wrong result instead of correct one. The correct one shows

```
class FibonacciIterator:
    def __init__(self, max):
        self.max = max

    def __iter__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 1
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        fib = self.a
        if fib > self.max:
            raise StopIteration
        self.a, self.b = self.b, self.a + self.b
        return fib
```

---

```
fib_ = FibonacciIterator(2)
for term in fib_:
    print(term,end=" ")
```

### Output:

```
Expected: 1 1
Got: 1 1 2
```

---

```
fib_nums = FibonacciIterator(5)
for term in fib_nums:
    print(term,end=" ")
```

### Output:

```
Expected: 1 1 2 3 5
Got : 1 1 2 3 5
```

Comment: Did you mean to start from 0, 1?

Comment: Your code would work only for max >= 5, since you are comparing fib and self.max which would not work for index < 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition to stop the iteration is wrong. You need to set a `self.counter` to zero in the `__init__` method, then in the `__next__` method increment this counter and in the condition compare it with max. The second case you got right by coincidence because the fifth element is five.

Comment: I'm glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

In this end condition `if fib > self.max:`, you're checking the last number in the series. You should check the `count` of numbers in the series to match the expected result.

You passed 2: your code printed the series till 2. You expected to print two numbers in the series. So, change the end condition.